# Find all matches preceded and followed by particular patterns

Tags: regex

I have a text document containing a complex text out of which i want to extract all the urls which are preceded by  `,imgurl:` and followed by `,oh:` like

```
,imgurl:"someurl",oh:
```

For example

```
,imgurl:"htp://absac.com/15.jpg",oh:

,imgurl:"htp://hdbc.com/16.jpg",oh:
```

the pattern i am trying is

```
",imgurl:[^,oh:]*oh:"
```

But it is giving me 0 matches

**Edit:** I am doing this in c#

Comment: Just match on the Quotes. Apparently they enclose your url. Assumung there ain't any other quotes per line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Using negative look arounds.

```
",imgurl:((?!,oh:).)*,oh:"
```

[^,oh:] would just exclude a certain character, not a longer string